# npm run watch not compiling when data is off

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, laravel-5.8

I am working with laravel and as well using a lot of node packages for development.
but the problem I have is that I am having a limited internet connection.

so whenever I run `npm run watch` it will not start until I have connected to the internet and after some hours, if I off my data connection it will stop compiling. I am on a windows machine.

My question is, is there an anything I can do so that the compilation can work in offline mode?

Or is there anything that I'm doing wrong?
I am currently working on laravel 5.8

below is my `package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.0",
        "admin-lte": "^3.0.0-alpha.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `package.json` file look like?  Can you upload the contents thereof into your question so we can see how you have `watch` configured?

Answer (score 1):

It is an online version, but you can add to the  package.json file this script

`"watch": "webpack --watch  --mode development",`

This way you can avoid unnecessary resources and actions during execution.
Where it looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "watch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch  --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

for more information see this:
https://jscraftsman.com/2018/08/15/setting-up-the-javascript-development-environment/

https://gist.github.com/jscraftsman/17f968a26340b01176ee71a724bcb914#file-package-json

https://blog.fellyph.com.br/javascript/webpack-mantendo-a-qualidade-do-seu-javascript/